# Thunderbird has always requested entering the master password multiple times

Tags: password, thunderbird

This has been annoying me for a long time. Here's the situation:

I have multiple accounts in Thunderbird.
I use a master password to access them.

Upon launching Thunderbird I get multiple prompts asking for the master password. If I am not mistaken the number of prompts = number of accounts I have.

My question is whether this is a bug or intentional. If intentional why is it given that it is a *master* password.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it is indeed a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176399) which is Gmail specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution but know a workaround.

Under "Server Settings" uncheck "Check for new messages at startup". Do this for all the email accounts.

This way you will have to enter the master password only once.

The drawback of this solution is that you won't see if you have new messages until you select "inbox" once.